# Storing values in chrome crossdomain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey

i made an user.js script which runs on multiple pages and does stuff.
However i need a way to store some values so user doesn't have to fill them in every time on every  page over and over again.

In firefox's greasemonkey I am using the setvalue function, which is great and does exactly what i want. 
In chrome, the alternative is localstorage, but unfortunately values stored this way are only accessible on the same domain where they were stored.

I need to be able to access the stored values on any page where my user.js  script is inserted (in chrome).

Is such thing possible? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [the Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and then your Greasemonkey script will work on Chrome, as is.

`GM_setvalue()` will work and will store values cross-domain, just like it does on Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, i can't really use this solution since i need it to work out of the box for all users without having to force them to install some extra extensions, but it's the closest answer available i guess, so i am marking it as solution. Thanks.

Comment: How is this different from Firefox, where the user is forced to install that Greasemonkey extension?!  With Chrome's new draconian, "install from the web store, or else" policy; installing Tampermonkey is actually easier, because it then allows userscripts to be installed/maintained/edited so much easier than with straight Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, but in Firefox you HAVE to install the monkey if you want to use scripts, in chrome the script support is built in and therefore users don't usually install anything additional and I am sure,  that users won't go into all the trouble with installing new extension just to accommodate one script.. And by the way yeah, that "install directly from store only"  policy was a total dick move.